# How to rewrite tail recursion as a cycle?

Tags: rust

I've written a simple variant of prefix tree:

```
struct Trie {
    data: Vec<Option<Trie>>
}

impl Trie {
    pub fn new() -> Trie {
        let mut data = Vec::with_capacity(26);
        for _ in 0..26 {
            data.push(None);
        }
        Trie { data: data }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, word: &str) {
        if word.len() != 0 {
            let idx = Trie::char_idx(word.char_at(0));
            let word_suffix = word.slice_from(1);
            if self.data[idx].is_none() {
                self.data[idx] = Some(Trie::new());
            } 
            self.data[idx].as_mut().unwrap().add(word_suffix)
        }
    }

    pub fn contain(&self, word: &str) -> bool {
        if word.len() == 0 {
            true
        } else {
            match self.data[Trie::char_idx(word.char_at(0))] {
                Some(ref next) => next.contain(word.slice_from(1)),
                None => false 
            }
        }
    }

    fn char_idx(chr: char) -> usize {
        (chr as u32 - 97) as usize
    }
}
```

It works Ok except the recursive nature of `add` function. Now, rust doesn't have tail call optimization, so I need to rewrite it as a cycle. 
This task should be trivial, but I cannot figure out the way to do it without borrow checker yelling at me.

Here is my naive approach:

```
pub fn add(&mut self, word: &str) {
    let mut current = self; 
    for chr in word.chars() {
        let idx = Trie::char_idx(chr);
        if current.data[idx].is_none() {
            current.data[idx] = Some(Trie::new());
        }
        current = current.data[idx].as_mut().unwrap();
    }
}
```

What can I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall reading other questions that ask the same conceptual question, but I cannot find them at the moment. Perhaps a kind soul will link them here.

That being said, this compiles:

```
pub fn add(&mut self, word: &str) {
    let mut current = self; 
    for chr in word.chars() {
        current = {
            let tmp = current;
            let idx = Trie::char_idx(chr);
            if tmp.data[idx].is_none() {
                tmp.data[idx] = Some(Trie::new());
            }
            tmp.data[idx].as_mut().unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

My general idea was to work-around the current fact that [borrow scopes are lexical](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6393). Inside of the for-loop, I create a new lexical scope and then reborrow `current` as `tmp`. We do our work on `tmp`, ultimately returning a reference that we then put back into `current`.

Comment: more golfing... You don't need a new scope, as long as you move something back into a variable you may move from it in a loop. Also, mutable self parameter: http://is.gd/aAE3a1

Answer (score 4):

A [`fold`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.fold) seems to do the trick:

```
pub fn add(&mut self, word: &str) {
    word.chars().fold(
        self,
        |current, chr| {
            let idx = Trie::char_idx(chr);
            if current.data[idx].is_none() {
                current.data[idx] = Some(Trie::new());
            }

            current.data[idx].as_mut().unwrap()
        });
}
```